# How to do the calculation of the error in positioning in 3D Space?

Tags: statistics, 3d

I'm mathematically calculating a position on given data in a program. But I need to validate that the calculated values against the original position value.

- If the Original position is Xi,Yi and Zi in which There can be m
  values (From i=1 to i=m)
- And for each original value the calculated n
  results show Xij, Yij and Zij (From j=1 to j=n)

How should i calculated the error?

Comment: There are many standard metrics, $\|\cdot\|_p$, but it really depends on what you want to get out of the error metric.

Comment: actually what i want to find is how accurate is the calculated value to the original. Should Something like RMS Error work?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. It could represent the worst case error or some average error, etc.